# file.create overwriting my declared path with the original app directory & my declared path vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need your help, I can not find any solving topic about it.

I have an app and I want to create a .cvs file, the method takes my declared path and re-writes it and adds the app directory path in front of my declared path, here is the coding and then the error.

```
    Public fileNameReport As String = ""

    fileNameReport = ""
    fileNameReport = "C:\Users\guillermo.velez\Documents\01.Guillermo V\Tests\" & Now & " Reject Report.csv"
    fileNameReport = fileNameReport.Replace("/", "")
    fileNameReport = fileNameReport.Replace(":", "")

    If Not File.Exists(fileNameReport) Then
        System.IO.File.Create(fileNameReport).Dispose()
    End If
```

The error is as follows:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\224135-6 Reject Control\224135-6 Reject Control\bin\Debug\C\Users(my user name)\Documents\01.Guillermo V\Tests\1132020 110900 AM Reject Report.csv'.'

Comment: does that path exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not replace `:` with empty string

```
fileNameReport = fileNameReport.Replace(":", "")
```

This converts path like `c:\` to `c\`

Please use DateTime formatting options to get date as a part of file name like

```
fileNameReport = string.Format("{0:ddMMyyyyhhmmss}Reject Report.csv", DateTime.Now)
dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) // this will return folder where executing assembly is located but you can put any value here
fileNameReport = Path.Combine(dirName, fileNameReport)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to create the file in "C:\Users\guillermo.velez\Documents\01.Guillermo V\Tests\". The part "C:\224135-6 Reject Control\224135-6 Reject Control\bin\Debug\" only appears because it tried to convert what it saw as a relative path (starting with "C\", as you pointed out) to an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you!! had not seen that, sorry for the inconvenience,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you oleksa I had not seen this, sorry, I have corrected my code and works fine now.

```
 fileNameReport = "C:\Users\guillermo.velez\Documents\01.Guillermo V\Tests\" & Now.ToString("MMddyyyy HHmmss") & " Reject Report.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have three suggestions:

1. Have the `Public` variable be a "base" you can use with `String.Format()` later on.
2. Use a format string instead of `String.Replace()` to clean up the date
3. Get rid of the `File.Create()` check. I've written about this often in the past, but generally speaking it's not something you want to do. Remember, the file system is volatile, meaning you still have to be able to handle an exception. Better to put your effort into the exception handler (which might be at a higher level of code... no need necessarily for a try/catch right here)

Put it all together:

```
Public Const fileNameReportBase As String = "C:\Users\guillermo.velez\Documents\01.Guillermo V\Tests\{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss} Reject Report.csv"

Dim fileNameReport As String = String.Format(fileNameReportBase, Now)
File.Create(fileNameReport)
```